# IBAction crashes TabBarController App

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, modalviewcontroller, ibaction

I have a Window-based TabBarController app and I'm trying to present a ModalView from one of the tabs (FirstViewController).  The app builds just fine and the tabs work, but upon clicking the "Open Modal View" button, it crashes and gives me:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController openModalView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5d1e930'
```

**UPDATE**: I have found that the issue is not with presenting the modal view but the crash happens with any IBAction calls.  what could be causing this?

FirstViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ModalViewController.h"

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController <ModalViewDelegate> {}
@end
```

FirstViewController.m:

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"

@implementation FirstViewController
- (IBAction) openModalView {
    ModalViewController *modalView=[[ModalViewController alloc] init];
    modalView.modalDelegate=self;
    [self presentModalViewController:modalView animated:YES];
    [modalView release];
}

 #pragma mark -
 #pragma mark ModalViewDelegate

- (void) didHitCancel {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

 #pragma mark - 

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}
- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
}
- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

ModalViewController.h:

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol ModalViewDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)didHitCancel;
@end

@interface ModalViewController : UIViewController {
    id modalDelegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) id<ModalViewDelegate> modalDelegate;

- (IBAction) cancel;

@end
```

ModalViewController.m:

```
 #import "ModalViewController.h"

@implementation ModalViewController

@synthesize modalDelegate;

- (IBAction) cancel {
    [self.modalDelegate didHitCancel];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
 }
 - (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
}
- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

I know this is a lot of code but I wanted to make sure someone could find the problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: lots of answers in Stackoverflow already http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529632/present-and-dismiss-modal-view-controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have the class on your custom view controller in IB Set to ModalViewController? That was my problem.

Comment: No I didn't.  I have long since figured it out, but that was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to put the openModalView method in the `@interface` of `FirstViewController`.

```
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController <ModalViewDelegate> {
}
- (IBAction) openModalView;
@end
```