# Opening a ModalView from a ModalView

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have created a splitview based application and in the appDelegate applicationdidFinishLaunchingWithOptions method i am showing a popup

```
(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)applicationdidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    [self.window addSubview:splitViewController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    ModalScreenPopup *modalpopup = [[ModalScreenPopup alloc] init];
    [modalpopup setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical];
    [modalpopup setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];

    [splitViewController presentModalViewController:modalpopup animated:NO];
    [modalpopup release];

    return YES;
}

(void) OpenTradeShowListingPopup
{
    [splitViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    TradeShowListing *modalTradeShowListing = [[TradeShowListing alloc] init];

    [modalTradeShowListing setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical];
    [modalTradeShowListing setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];

    [splitViewController presentModalViewController:modalTradeShowListing animated:YES];

    [modalTradeShowListing release];
}
```

ModalScreenPopup has 2 buttons name Synchronize and continue with app when I click on the synchronize button I am calling OpenTradeShowListingPopup method which is declared in the appDelegate. That method calls another popup but now first modal is getting dismissed but second popup is not getting called.

---

I have solved my problem by using UINavigationController  this post really help me a lot A guy name JNOXX has helped me on Mac Forums here is [the link](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1123957).

Thanks 7KV7 for helping me.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the issue

```
[splitViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Try instead

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: Hey 7kv7 my Modal view is getting dismissed but the new modalview is not getting called :(

Comment: can you try to self for presenting and dismissing all modalview controllers

Comment: by using self its shows the warning: 'MyAppDelegate' may not respond to '-presentModalViewController:animated:' and its not working :(

Comment: Oh so this method is in the app delegate. Hang on

Comment: pls go through this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529632/present-and-dismiss-modal-view-controller. It will give you an idea.

Comment: Can you pls check if it works if u write TradeShowListing *modalTradeShowListing = [[TradeShowListing alloc] init];

    [modalTradeShowListing setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical];
    [modalTradeShowListing setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];

    [splitViewController presentModalViewController:modalTradeShowListing animated:YES];
instead of ModalScreenPopup and see if its presented

Comment: Yes at that time its getting presented.

Comment: ok can you also check if splitviewcontroller exists when u try to present TradeShowListing

Comment: can u just check this app i have created the replica of my issue in my sample app if i post the link can u have a look at it

Comment: how can i check if my splitview exists or not ?

Comment: I am sorry I don't have a Mac machine now. :(

Comment: Just put a breakpoint in the method and see print the values of the ones you want to check on the console.

Comment: yaa i have put the test values using NSLog and the values are getting print. but tell me 1 thing if the splitviewcontroller dosent exists and when the code reaches that line then the app will crash right ? if right then splitviewcontroller exists

Comment: but the app is not getting crash also..........so can u suggest me a different workaround for the same functionality

Comment: Yes let me try to find a solution

Comment: In case u wanna see the code here is the link of my sample application [link]http://www.filefactory.com/file/ca4001f/n/2_Modal.zip[/link]