# Accessing a view controller created through Storyboard using the App Delegate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, delegates, ios5, storyboard

I'm working on an iOS5 app using storyboard, and I have a method in a view controller class that i'd like to access from the App Delegate.  The trouble is, this view controller gets instantiated via a tab bar controller in storyboard, so the App Delegate has no direct way of calling the method I want...

For a view controller to get in touch with the App Delegate, all one has to do is use:

```
MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

Is there a similarly easy way of pointing to an already-instantiated view controller or class?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'll have to traverse the view hierarchy from the app delegate.  Assuming the `AppDelegate` holds a reference to the `UITabBarController`, you could use the `viewControllers` property or `selectedViewController` property to get to your view controller.

Comment: So...an outlet from the tab bar in storyboard to the app delegate, and then figure out the tab bar's properties to find the view controller I need?  Any reason not to just create a direct outlet from the view controller itself, since that's in storyboard too?

Comment: Ok, there is no way to create an outlet to the app delegate from the storyboard, so my statement was a little incorrect.  There is a window property on the app delegate that is set automatically by the storyboard and it has a rootViewController property.  That will be the first view controller in the storyboard.  From there you should be able to get to the view you need.

Comment: Bam!  That did it...though it is a bit of a pain traversing all the views.  Thanks, Jerry!

Comment: @jerry can u suggest some solution for a similar issue of mine.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21373470/access-a-view-controller-from-appdelgate-using-storyboard

Answer (score 15):

Thanks to Jerry (above), here's the code that got me what I wanted:

```
    UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
MasterViewController *result;

//check to see if navbar "get" worked
if (navigationController.viewControllers) 

    //look for the nav controller in tab bar views 
    for (UINavigationController *view in navigationController.viewControllers) {

        //when found, do the same thing to find the MasterViewController under the nav controller
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]])
            for (UIViewController *view2 in view.viewControllers) 
                if ([view2 isKindOfClass:[MasterViewController class]])                    
                    result = (MasterViewController *) view2;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

I probably would do it in reverse.  Create a method in AppDelegate call registerViewController or something.  In every ViewController, call the method with itself with a name.  Then in AppDelegate, you can do whatever you want afterward.  It is messy to do all sort of drill

In AppDelegate

```
- (void)registerViewController:(NSString *)name controller:(UIViewController *)controller
{
    if(_viewControllers == nil)
    {
        _viewControllers = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    }

    [_viewControllers setObject:controller forKey:name];
}
```

In any ViewController

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [appDelegate registerViewController:@"feelings" controller:self];
}
```

In AppDelegate

```
XViewController *vc = (XViewController *)[_viewControllers objectForKey:@"X"];
[X startSpinner];
```

Hope this help

BS

Comment: great idea,but XViewController should be remove from _viewControllers when dealloc and I must remember many keys if there are many view controllers I need to access in app delegate.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using a storyboard, and you want instance of a viewController in storyboard you can use the following

```
UIStoryboard *mystoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
id viewcontroller = [mystoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"identifier"];
```

Here the 'identifier' is the name provided in the particular viewController's 'storyBoard ID' in 'Identity' section in 'Identity Inspector'.

Comment: This worked great. Would you have any guidance on how to also load my tab bar and navigation controllers?

Answer (score 6):

I have a better solution. You can use `window.rootViewController.storyboard` to get a reference to the storyboard of that view.

Answer (score 2):

In the AppDelegate, you could simply use indexes to access the controllers via UITabBarController:

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
firstViewController = [[tabBarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
secondViewController = [[tabBarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:1];
thirdViewController = [[tabBarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:2];
```

Naturally, this will get messed up if you change the ordering of the tab bar. Also, if you're looking for a controller deeper in the hierarchy, you need to do a bit more legwork.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift**

This is the Swift version of @infiniteLoop's answer.

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let myViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("identifier") as! MyViewController
```

You need to replace the storyboard name, view controller name, and view controller identifier with whatever you used in your project.

**Related tasks**

- [Pass data to the view controller](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31934786/3681880)
- [Present and dismiss a view controller modally](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37274189/3681880)