# Get StoryBoard instance of View Controller

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, instance, uistoryboard

Example without storyboard:

AppDelegate.h

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) UIViewController *leftController;
```

AppDelegate.m

```
self.leftController = [[LeftViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LeftViewController" bundle:nil];
```

OtherViewController:

```
//This is what I want do to in storyboards
self.viewDeckController.leftController = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate].leftController;
```

How can I get that instance of leftController when using storyboards?

Answer (score 28):

You can give the view controller an identifier in interface builder, then simply use:

```
UIStoryboard *mystoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"myStoryBoardName" bundle:nil];
self.leftController = [mystoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"idyouassigned"];
```

Comment: Wouldn't this return new view controller?
 I want to point to already created view controller.

Comment: @1337code See my edit. I'm not sure if I'm understanding what you are trying to do. If in your app delegate you wish to create "leftController" with the contents of a view controller in a storyboard, you'll want to use the code I've provided.

Comment: Please take a look at this: https://github.com/Inferis/ViewDeck
I want to use it with storyboard, check the description and how to change views.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether you able to get solutions of this problem or not, but you can also refer the answer of this question :

[Accessing view controller form a storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8784143/accessing-a-view-controller-created-through-storyboard-using-the-app-delegate)