# Access a view controller from appdelegate using storyboard

Tags: ios7, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller, appdelegate

I have followed this Ray Wendelich Tutorial
[RayWenderlichTutorial Tabbarcontroller using storyboards](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50308/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1)

Just see the storyboard image.
Ray is accesing 'playersViewcontroller using the below code'

```
 UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
UINavigationController *navigationController = [tabBarController viewControllers][0];
PlayersViewController *playersViewController = [navigationController viewControllers][0];
```

When I'm trying to access playerDetailsViewController, using the following code i get a crash. Giving the message

> Ratings[2630:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (0x30b49e83 0x3aea66c7 0x30a7fff9 0x3ddd1 0x3333eaad 0x3333e4f3 0x33338b41 0x332d3a07 0x332d2cfd 0x33338321 0x357b876d 0x357b8357 0x30b14777 0x30b14713 0x30b12edf 0x30a7d471 0x30a7d253 0x333375c3 0x33332845 0x3e0fd 0x3b39fab7)
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

the code

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController =
(UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
UINavigationController *navigationController =
[[tabBarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
PlayersViewController *playersViewController =
[[navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];

UINavigationController *nav=[[navigationController viewControllers]objectAtIndex:1];
PlayerDetailsViewController *playerdetailsviewcontroller=[[nav viewControllers]objectAtIndex:0];
```

I tried the below code also,

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController =
(UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
UINavigationController *navigationController =
[[tabBarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
PlayersViewController *playersViewController =
[[navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
PlayerDetailsViewController *playerdetailsviewcontroller=[[navigationController viewControllers]objectAtIndex:1];
```

where i get a crash with message

> 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'

The storyboard image
[image]

Basically i want to access the PlayerdetailsViewcontroller from appdelegate.
I think I'm missing something, any thoughts?

Comment: Could you post a screen of your storyboard? Or more information what did you do with your storyboard. Then I will try answer your question

Comment: i have edited the question ,if you zoom a little bit you can see the names of the viewcontrollers

Answer (score 1):

Your app crashes here (`objectAtIndex:1`):

```
UINavigationController *nav = [[navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:1];
PlayerDetailsViewController *playerdetailsviewcontroller = [[nav viewControllers]objectAtIndex:0];
```

This happens because `naviationController` has only 1 subview (`PlayersViewController`). You can't go further down the storyboard without instantiating the `PlayerDetailsViewController` within `PlayersViewController` via a Segue.

**EDIT**
You can only access the `ViewControllers` that are initially visible (via the `UITabBarController`).

I also don't get why you're adding another `UINavigationController` to the `PlayersViewController`. If you connect `PlayersViewController` to `PlayerDetailViewController` with a Segue the `navigationController` will be reused (this would be the correct way to do so).

Comment: is there any way to access the view controller if i do the above things you said?

Comment: yes, you can access it through `PlayersViewController` and also pass on data from your `AppDelegate` to `PlayersViewController` and to `PlayerDetailsViewController`

Comment: ya i solved it using what Hannes has told ,accessed it through the playerViewController instead of app delegate.UJSed prepare for Segue method

Comment: is there any way to access playerDeatailsViewcontroller from app delegate if i  connected playersViewController and playerDetailsViewcontroller using segue.? I want to access from app delegate.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a modal segue from Players to Player Details.  So you could use the presentedViewController property of PlayersViewController, something like this

```
PlayersViewController *playersViewController = [navigationController.viewControllers firstObject];
UINavigationController *secondNavigationController = playersViewController.presentedViewController;
PlayerDetailsViewController *playerDetailsViewController = [secondNavigationController.viewControllers firstObject];
```