# How to launch a new screen in IOS?

Tags: ios

This is a very simple question, but I don't find how to do it.

The first thing I found was that I have to add a navigation controller. Although I don't need to show a navigation controller, I tried it.
I found these tutorials:
http://www.ralfebert.de/tutorials/iosdev/navigationcontroller/

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Creating_a_Navigation_based_iOS_4_iPhone_Application_using_TableViews

http://iosmadesimple.blogspot.de/2012/09/navigation-based-project-doing-it-using.html

and others, where it says, I have to connect the navigation controller to window object. But in the .xib there is no window object. There seems to be some update, I found window object created programmatically in AppDelegate.m

Does it mean that I have to connect them programmatically, if yes, how?

I'm using Xcode 4.4.1 building for 5.1.

Then I found hacky approach, to replace views described here: http://fuelyourcoding.com/ios-basics-how-to-load-a-uiview-without-a-navigation-controller/

But I want to know what's the standard way to do it.

In Apple's dev guide is something about storyboards. Is that what I need?

I need to know how I launch a separate, new screen (with own controller and .xib of course), if possible, without having to add a navigation bar to the app.

Comment: There are tasks which are easier to solve using code than using IB. This is one of them.

Comment: Well, in Android it's very easy to switch screens, with 2 lines of code. No relation with the layout files. But I put "ios launch new screen" in Google and get how to add a splash screen to the app and other non sense. I thought it would be 1 minute, basic stuff.

Comment: The Google problem happens because it doesn't know how to translate between APIs.  I didn't get very good results when looking for "android push view controller" either.  :-)

Comment: @Ixx I am going to disappoint you: it's also very easy in iOS, you're just not experienced enough.

Comment: @Phillip Mills It was just an example, I also put "launch new view controller", etc. etc. and didn't get what I'm looking for. Besides, I'm a beginner, and I need a clear article, otherwise I don't know if I'm implementing the standard solution or a hack. And I also couldn't find (quickly) a clear statement in Apple's devs guide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to do this is to use a navigation controller.

In the AppDelegate applicationWillFinishLaunchingWithOptions put this...

```
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:<the view controller you want to use first>];

self.window.rootViewController = self.navController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

This will launch your app with a NavigationController and the first thing you see will be your initial view controller.

To hide the bar...

In the viewWillAppear part of your initial view controller...

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

This will hide the navigation bar for that controller.

To push to a new view controller...

```
MyNewViewController *newVc = [[MyNewViewController... (set it up).

[self.navigationController pushViewController:newVc animated:YES];
```

This is done from the initial view controller.

Then to pop back.  In the new VC just do this...

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

You'll never really "own" the navigation controller and you'll never really see it.  It just sits behind your app managing the transitions and stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You can show a modal view if you don't want to use a NavigationController. In this SO question you can find how to do it: [Present and dismiss modal view controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529632/present-and-dismiss-modal-view-controller)

Presenting a view with a NavigationController or not depends on the purpose of that view and it is in relationship with your screens flow. If you have to "Drill Down" into a series of UITableViews or just navigate through different screens before you reach the specific one, you should use a UINavigationController to handle that. Take a look at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

I personally prefere using StoryBoards for apps that has a considerable amount of views because it help me have a clear "picture" of their hierarchy and also the relationships between each one.

In the end it's just a matter of taste. If you want to learn more about StoryBoards, I recommend you this post: http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1

In case you want to know how to create a modal view with StoryBoards, the easiest way to show it is by creating a new project, selecting the option "Single View Application" and the checking the option "Use Storyboards" in the next screen. Once you have that you have to select your "MainStoryboard.storyboard" file inside your project folder in Xcode. Then drag a "View Controller" (the first orange circle with a square on it) from the bottom right corner and drop it into your StoryBoard, next to the one that was already created.

Now you should have two different ViewControllers. Just drag a UIButton from your bottom right corner (you'll need to scroll through the list to see the "Round Rect Button" option) to the first ViewController (the one that has an arrow pointing to it from the left).

And finally you have to hold Control + Click on that UIButton and link that button with the other ViewController. Once you do this it will present the "Action Segue" dialog. Just select Modal and voila!

This is how your StoryBoard should look like:

[image: modal view controller]

**Note**: I've changed the color of the second ViewController to make it more evident the switch.

I recommend you read the raywenderlich's tutorial first and then do your modal view following this steps.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    YourViewController *viewController = [[YourViewController alloc] init];
    navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
    // Add the view controller's view to the window and display.
    [window addSubview:navController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: The addSubview line gives me: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency', reason: 'adding a root view controller <ViewController: 0x6a60390> as a child of view controller:<UINavigationController: 0x6bd0c20>'