# self.tabBarController dismissViewControllerAnimated doesn't work

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a UITabBarController in my application.

I would like to present from one tab, another UIViewController.

So I wrote in `ViewControllerA` (which is a tab in the tabviewcontroller):

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
MyViewController *chooseTemplateController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myController"];
[self.tabBarController presentViewController:myController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

This shows MyViewController nicely.

However, how can I dismiss MyViewController?

I read in many questions that I need to call:

```
[self.tabBarController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
```

However - where do I call it from? I tried from MyViewController - but since it's not part of the UITabBar, self.tabBarController is null.

I initialize the UiTabBarController from storyboard and not from appDelegate and I would like to leave it that way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the presented viewController's `presentingViewController` property

#### Objective-C

```objc
[self.presentingViewController  dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
```

#### Swift

```swift
presentingViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
```

You can also use this shorthand version (I don't recommend you do, but you will see it often)

#### Objective-C

```objc
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
```

#### Swift

```swift
dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
```

see
[Dismissing a Presented View Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14636891/dismissing-a-presented-view-controller/14637067#14637067)