# Navigate Back to previous view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I have a `UIView->UICollectionView->UICollectionViewCell`. I am trying to navigate back programatically but none of these works. The code did called.
I am using StoryBoard.

```
- (void) goBack:(NSNotification *) notification {
      // [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
     //  [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
      [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: show me your button action code or notification code?

Comment: Are you getting self.navigationControlle as not nil in your class? Check this.

Comment: [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"goBack" object:nil];

Comment: Did you register for the notification with addObserver:selector:name:object:?

Comment: What are you trying to navigate back to? The 3 objects you show in your question are all views, not view controllers. What controllers do you have?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

You need to use:

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

This will bring you back to the root view controller.

If you want to navigate back to previous view controller, you should implement:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: Have you set UINavigationController as your rootViewController ? If not, then it will not work.

Answer (score 19):

By using below line we can go to parent view controller

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

By using below line we can move to main/root view controller

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

By using below line we can move to any view controller

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController:viewControllerObject animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 4):

How about...

```
 [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Assuming that you are currently in a navigation-based controller and you wanted to go back to the previous controller before you got into a navigation-based controller.

Answer (score 4):

With swift3,

```
@IBAction func back(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)     
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Swift 4.1:

```
navigationController.popViewController(animated: true)
```

Answer (score 3):

Swift solutions for easy copy pasting:

```
navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try it....

```
#import "bookdescriViewController.h" // import here your class name 

- (IBAction)backButton:(id)sender 
{
  bookdescriViewController *previosVC = [[bookdescriViewController alloc]init];
  [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]; // go to previous view controller
  [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES]; // go to root view controller
  [self.navigationController popToViewController:previosVC animated:YES]; // go to any view controller
  [previosVC release];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Go back to parent view controller and dealloc current view controller ex :

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSInteger numberOfViewControllers = self.navigationController.viewControllers.count;

    UIViewController *vc = [self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:numberOfViewControllers - 2];

    [self.navigationController popToViewController:vc animated:NO];
}
```

or another view controller

Answer (score -1):

```
- (void) goBack:(NSNotification *) notification 
{ 
   if(!self.YOrView.isHidden)
      self.YOrView.hidden = YES;
}
```