# programmatic navigation back button not showing

Tags: ios, swift

[image]

here is my code at the appdelegate:

```
  func showMainView()
  {
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let secondViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PRODUCT_TABBAR_VC_ID")
    let nav = UINavigationController()
    nav.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)
    self.window!.rootViewController = nav
    self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
  }
```

simulator output:

[image]

basicaly i want when user press back button then came back main page . i mean initial page .

i am trying with this one but it not working at least one answer for me [Navigate Back to previous view controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16075525/navigate-back-to-previous-view-controller)

Note : @matt said **it is imposible. so  could you tell me please what should i do . i am new to iOS**

**Update:**

when user select **Man** that time tabviewcontroller two page only showing list of product about **Man**. so if user want to see **Woman** then user back to main page to select **Woman** then  he will see **Woman** tabviewcontroller two page.

Answer (score 0):

The back button is for returning to an earlier view controller pushed onto a UINavigationController. In your code, there is no back button because there is nothing to come back to; `secondViewController` is the *only* view controller pushed onto the UINavigationController.

Comment: could you tell me please what should i do . i am new to iOS

Comment: please suggest me . what can i do

Comment: I don't know what you _want_ to do. You are _on_ the main/initial page. There is nothing to go back to. The whole question makes no sense.

Comment: could you check my update image . for example : when user select **Man** that time tabviewcontroller two page only showing list of product about **Man**. so if user want to see **Woman** then user back to main page to select **Woman** then  he will see **Woman** tabviewcontroller two page .

Comment: Well, when your code said `self.window!.rootViewController = nav`, you completely threw away in the Man / Woman page. You cannot go "back" to it because it no longer even exists. It was the root view controller, but instead of navigating from it, you just deleted it. Thus there is nothing to go back to.

Answer (score 0):

Place following lines within `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` in AppDelegate.swift

```
self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: FirstViewController())
self.window!.rootViewController = nav
self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Create FirstViewController.swift with following:

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let button1 = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))
        button1.setTitle("Man", for: .normal)
        button1.tag = 1
        self.view.addSubview(button1)
        button1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(showAction(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        let button2 = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 250, width: 200, height: 200))
        button2.setTitle("Woman", for: .normal)
        button2.tag = 2
        self.view.addSubview(button2)
        button2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(showAction(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    }

    func showAction(sender: UIButton) {
        let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let secondViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PRODUCT_TABBAR_VC_ID")
        if (sender.tag == 1) {
            // SHOW MAN
        } else if (sender.tag == 2) {
            // SHOW WOMAN
        }
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)
    }

}
```

Comment: You can work even further with FirstViewController and add one more button, within `viewDidLoad`

Answer (score 0):

You should create your hierarchy like so:

```
                                                                             ----> UIViewController
----> UINavigationController ----> UIViewController ----> UITabBarController
                                                                             ----> UIViewController
```

EDIT: It will look like that: [image]

This way it will be possible to pop UIViewControllers contained in UITabBarController.

Comment: If I get it correct you want to show tabbar in both cases: when user selects Man or Woman. If that tabbar is no different (it have same views with same type of data) then you can just customise data contained inside. Below is example code how you can achieve that:

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
    {
        if segue.identifier == "identifier"
        {
            let destinationController = segue.destination as? YourCustomController
            // do your task
        }
    }