# Attempt to present a viewcontroller whose view is not in the window hierarchy

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I have a tab bar application. My requirement is I select the 'scan' tab to scan the qr code and navigate/jump immediatley to another 'list' tab. Both 'scan' and 'list' tab are there in the viewControllers array in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` After referring [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16384121/warning-attempt-to-present-viewcontroller-on-viewcontroller-whose-view-is-not-i) link, i don't think i need to set the delegate as both the tabs are already present in the hierarchy.

I get this warning in the following line

```
    if(x)
    {
    listViewCntrl = [[ListViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ListViewController" bundle:nil];
    listViewCntrl.getFlag = YES;
    [self presentViewController:listViewCntrl animated:YES completion:Nil]; // I get the warning here
    }
```

If I comment out the above code and add

```
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
```

then I would not be able to get the subView of the listViewController (set flag to show the subview) which i need to display inside the list tab after scanning.

App crashes if I add

```
[self.tabBarController setSelectedViewController:listViewCntrl];
```

So how do I display the listView's subview after scanning?

Answer (score 0):

```
ListViewController *listController = (ListViewController*)[self.tabController viewControllers][1];
listController.getFlag = 1;
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
```

The problem is that you're creating an entirely new `ListViewController`. You say you already have one in the tab controller - you don't need a new one.

You can't use your 3rd option because, again, the two ListViewController's are different objects (they may be of the same class, but they point to a different address).

Comment: I get this error for flag [UINavigationController setGetFlag:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance and it does not navigate to index:1 if I comment out the flag line

Comment: @OptimusPrime Right, sure, so you have a UINavigationController for that particular tab, then I guess ListViewController is somewhere in the navigation stack. I know next to nothing about your application so I can't really give you a definitive answer here, but try out the `viewControllers` or `topViewController` properties on UINavigationController.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this if you use storyboard:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
ViewController * destViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewControllerIdentifier"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:destViewController animated:YES];
```

You have to set an identifier for your controller in your storyboard.

Comment: i did not use storyboard in my project. Also if i use [self.navigationController ...] it will navigate within the same tab. I need to change the tab index as well. Thats my requirement.