# How can I programmatically present a view controller modally?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

**Edit:** When solving this problem, I found that it is much easier to start with your `UITabBarController`, then perform login validation *via* your `AppDelegate.m`'s `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method.

*Question:*
This code is in the the `application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method in my AppDelegate.m

```
if([result isEqualToString: @"log"])
{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *ivc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TabBarControl"];
    [(UINavigationController*)self.window.rootViewController pushViewController:ivc animated:NO];
    NSLog(@"It's hitting log");
}
```

It simply takes an HTTP response for **the user being logged in**, and takes them to my TabBarController. The problem is that it's using a **push** rather than a **modal** transition to display the page. Since presentModalViewController method is deprecated or deleted in iOS7, how can I programmatically force a modal presentation?

**EDIT:**
[image])

Comment: All you need to do is look in the reference docs for this method and it will show you what to use in its place.

Comment: You should not use segues to go backwards (other than an unwind segue) to previous controllers, which it looks like you're doing in this image. This will cause new controllers to be instantiated, not go back to the one you started with.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

## Swift

This is how you would do it in Swift without referencing the navigation controller:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let secondViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "secondViewController") as! SecondViewController
self.present(secondViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Change the storyboard name, view controller, and id as needed.

See also [how to dismiss a view controller programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37740006/3681880).

Comment: If you want to do this from an arbitrary UI context, you can UIWindow.visibleVC?.present

Answer (score 2):

In swift 4.2 you can do it like this. For those who want this answer in swift updated version.

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ExampleViewController")
self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 3/4

```
     let storyB = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil) 
     let secondViewController = storyB.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewControllerID") as! SecondViewController
     self.present(secondViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 let storyB = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil) 
 let secondViewController = 
 storyB.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: 
 "SecondViewControllerID") as! SecondViewController
 self.present(secondViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

In the secondViewController use this code to go back.

```
 self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```