# Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted

Tags: ios, navigationbar

I have two different push perform in view controller as below:

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{  

     indexPathRow = indexPath.row;  

     NSLog(@"indexPathRow.%d", indexPathRow);  

    safetyInventoryList.recordIdToEdit = [DeviceIdArray objectAtIndex:indexPathRow] intValue];  

    NSLog(@"Item selected..%d", inventoryList.recordIdToEdit);  

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"DetailsViewController" sender:nil];  

}  



 -(IBAction)ViewScoreBtn:(id)sender {  

     [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ScoreViewController" sender:nil];  

 }
```

I get the following error and black screen when i click back button after entering "viewscore" button ->  VC.

```
nested push animation can result in corrupted navigation bar  
Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted.  
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't add self as subview'
```

Updated code:in prepare for segue I have following (in my presenting VC):(.m)

```
 if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ScoreViewController"]){  
        ScoreViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;  
        destViewController.delegate = self;  
    }
```

and

```
 - (void)dismissScoreViewController:MVVMScoreViewController{  
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion: nil];  
 }
```

in my presented VC(.h &.m):

```
@protocol dismissScoreDelegate <NSObject>  

 - (void)dismissScoreViewController:SafetyDeviceViewController;  

@end  
 @property (nonatomic, assign) id<dismissScoreDelegate> delegate;  

 -(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    if ([self.navigationController.viewControllers indexOfObject:self]==NSNotFound) {
        // Navigation button was pressed. Do some stuff
        [self.delegate dismissScoreViewController];
     }
   [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
 }
```

So what's going wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dismissing a Presented View Controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14636891/dismissing-a-presented-view-controller)

Comment: Sorry, I am new to iOS and I did not get it completely.

Comment: I suggest you read up Apple documentation on View controllers: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog

Answer (score 0):

1.comment the perform segue that cause this error

2.run the project

3.tap the button/action from where it is intended to perform the navigation

4.Check for the duplication or multiple segue perform.

i got this due to the multiple segue activity from single button action.

Answer (score 0):

Use unwind segue instead of pop , it will work fine