# dismissViewControllerAnimated doesn't call it's completion handle

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, presentviewcontroller, ios9.3

dismissViewController doesn't call it's completing handler all the time. I am presenting first view, when I dismiss it, it calls completion handler, where I am presenting 2 view. While dismissing 2nd view, completion handler is not being called. Here is my code:

```
if self.presentedViewController != nil {
// Checking it to make sure that I have presentedViewController and it is not dismissed already.
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: {            
         //Present 2nd controller.
    })
}
```

Comment: where have you put this code?

Comment: if you dismiss self, won't the vc deallocate before it can run the completion block?

Comment: When `animation` parameter is set to `false`, completion block will NOT be called because the code is synchronous and can be placed outside the block..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [modal View controllers - how to display and dismiss](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14907518/modal-view-controllers-how-to-display-and-dismiss)

Comment: Also see [Dismissing a Presented View Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14636891/dismissing-a-presented-view-controller)

Answer (score 0):

You can not present a second UIViewController from the dismissed UIViewController because you are dismissing the "presenter".

You need to put your "Present 2nd controller" in your PRESENTING UIViewController **that is before** **(presenting)** the UIViewController you are dismissing.

Basically, you dismiss the UIViewController and when you come back to your presenting VC, you present the 2nd controller instead.