# Dismiss second ViewController from the third ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller, dismiss

I am trying to dismiss VC b from VC c where VC c is a popover and has a button for sign out but it is not working.
The structure of the flow is

```
VC a ----presents modally----> VC b ----presents a popover----> VC c
```

When the button in the popover is clicked the VC c and VC b must be dismissed so that (VC a)ViewWillAppear is called.

Comment: Show the code you have tried

Comment: i have tried this but this isn't working:         self.presentingViewController?.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: Can you please share the code that presenting VC a

Comment: Make sure you see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14907518/5175709). It's objective-c, but has a great detailed answer. Also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14636891/dismissing-a-presented-view-controller)

Answer (score 4):

**Try this:**

You can dismiss your `presentingViewController` from child view controller as follow

```
self.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

When you add a ViewController as childViewController

```
self.parent?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

If this view controller is a child of a containing view controller (e.g. a navigation controller or tab bar
      controller,)

```
weak open var parent: UIViewController? { get }
```

The view controller that was presented by this view controller or its nearest ancestor.

```
open var presentedViewController: UIViewController? { get }
```

The view controller that presented this view controller (or its farthest ancestor.)

```
open var presentingViewController: UIViewController? { get }
```

Comment: How to present vc B to vc C provide this

Comment: Provides  more info like how to present your vc C from vc B.

Comment: i have called a story board segue to be performed in VC b as performSegue(withIdentifier: "pop", sender: self)   in an ibaction. this segue is presenting VC can a popover

Comment: how could i assign parent value of a VC because it is a get only property.

Comment: check updated answer ` self.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) ` @bakhtiarmasood

Answer (score 0):

If `ViewControllers` have hierarchy like

VC a ----presents as `self.present(objects, animated: true, completion: nil)` modally----> VC b ----   presents as `self.present(objects, animated: true, completion: nil)` popover----> VC c

And there are a button on VC c to move back to VC a then you can use:

```
self.presentingViewController?.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: its not working i have tried it for thousands of times

Comment: What is the result, what happens?

Comment: Can you please show your code which show how you present VC b and VC c

Comment: VC b is shown like  performSegue(withIdentifier: "rewards", sender: nil)  and VC c is shown like  performSegue(withIdentifier: "pop", sender: self)

Comment: please check button @IBAction is called or not.

Answer (score 0):

First of all try to dismiss VC b from itself, not presenting the VC c just to check if it works, using: `self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)` or if VC b is embedded in a navigation controller, like this: `self.navigationController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)`

If the one from above works, I would suggest you implement the delegation protocol, where VC c will delegate to VC b the dismissal, whenever it should be done. You could also use a completion block for that, containing the `dismiss` code.

Comment: but VC c does not cover the current context it is actually a popover so if user doesn't click on the popover but some where else the popover that is VC c will disappear but there would be no VC b beneath it to be displayed that would be contradictory with the flow

Answer (score 0):

> Hope this works

```
// Call inside View controller C    
        self.presentingViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
        self.presentingViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
`protocol ModalHandler {
    func modalDismissed()
Class SecondViewController: UIViewController, ModalHandler {
    func modalDismissed() {
        self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
   }
   func open3rdController() {
       let thirdVC = ThirdViewController(_ )
       thirdVC.delegate = self
       self.present(thirdVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
   }
class ThirdViewController: UIViewController {
    func dismiss() {
        self.delegate.modalDismissed()
   }
}
`
```

Answer (score 0):

Whats about a `Presenter` or a `Coordinator`.

This instance will initialize all these VCs and also present them.
From there you can also dismiss them.