# Can't switch back to original view

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm writing an iPhone app and I start with a main view and when I click a button it switches to my second view using this code...

```
- (IBAction)addNewCourse
{
    AddCourses *addCourseController = [[AddCourses alloc] initWithNibName:@"AddCourses" bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:addCourseController animated:YES];

}
```

Now I am having problems switching BACK to the original view.  I use this code...

```
- (IBAction) back
{
    [self.parentViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

but it doesn't seem to work.  Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Present and dismiss modal view controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529632/present-and-dismiss-modal-view-controller)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```