# How to keep rootViewController always on top

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am a beginner in ObjC and I'm making a game using Sparrow Framework 1.4
I'm trying to add video ad into the app. I followed the instruction from the ad SDK and put these lines of code in AppDelegate:

viewController = [[FWPlayerViewController alloc] init];

window.rootViewController = viewController;

When I run the project, I can hear the audio, but not the video. My game screen is showing, so I'm thinking that the video ad is not visible because it is playing under Sparrow view.

Is there a way to launch this video ad viewController so that it'll always be visible (on top of everything)? Thanks!

Comment: If you hide the Sparrow VC can you see the video?

Comment: I tried that by running the ad code and commenting the rest of sparrow, and I get a blank pink screen.

Comment: Work on getting the video running then - that's probably the problem then.

Comment: I think that blank pink screen is Sparrow's background, because if I run the ad in a separate project (no Sparrow) I can see the video. So I tried to add the ad viewController.view as Sparrow subview. Now I can see the ad frame box (!), but the ad is not running (no voice, empty black window).

Comment: Ahhh OK that changes things then. What happens if you present the video as a modal view controller popup instead?

Comment: Being a novice in ObjC, I don't know how to do that. I will look around and try to do that and report back..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529632/present-and-dismiss-modal-view-controller :)