# Instantiate and Present a viewController in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiviewcontroller

### Issue

I started taking a look on the `Swift Programming Language`, and somehow I am not able to correctly type the initialization of a `UIViewController` from a specific `UIStoryboard`.

In `Objective-C` I simply write:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"StoryboardName" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewControllerID"];
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Can anyone help me on how to achieve this on Swift?

Answer (score 743, accepted):

*This answer was last revised for Swift 5.4 and iOS 14.5 SDK.*

---

It's all a matter of new syntax and slightly revised APIs. The underlying functionality of UIKit hasn't changed. This is true for a vast majority of iOS SDK frameworks.

```swift
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "myStoryboardName", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "myVCID")
self.present(vc, animated: true)
```

Make sure to set `myVCID` inside the storyboard, under "Storyboard ID."

[image]

Comment: You can even omit the `;`! ;) Would you mind elaborating on the `as UIViewController`? Why is that necessary?

Comment: `as` keyword is used for typecasting. It's the same as `(UIViewController *)anObject` in objective c

Comment: Yeah I know I can omit them but that's a part of the long habbit. :D  As `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` returns `AnyObject` (`id` equivalent in Swift) and I declare `vc` as `UIViewController`, I have to typecast `AnyObject` to `UIViewController`.

Comment: Hi Friends, i am facing some different issue, This code run on simulator not on my ipad2 which having iOS v7.1.2. If you dont mind help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: the "as UIViewController" can also be "as CustomViewControllerSubclass". You're not always going to want to instantiate *just* a UIViewController from a storyboard.

Comment: @akashivskyy Most definitely, to you. But maybe not to some.

Comment: with Swift 1.2, the `as` should be changed to `as!` (more info: https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=23)

Comment: As of Swift 2 `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` returns `UIViewController` so you don't need to unroll anymore. So things simplify: `let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MyStoryboardName", bundle: nil);
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("someViewController"); self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)`

Comment: for ios9  as! UIViewController no need it "Forced cast of 'UIViewController' to same type has no effect"

Comment: If I go to second viewController in tabBarController, How do I do? If I direct to second viewController than does not show TavBarController.

Comment: Is it necessary to instantiate the storyboard object each time or I thing it can be made static to reuse it. Am I correct with this approach.

Comment: @akashivskyy In the new syntax. I don't need 
the extra "as UINavigationController" then?
In
let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "someViewController")

Comment: I don't think completion is required.

Comment: it's better to use with navigation `self.navigationController?.show(controller, sender: nil)`

Comment: @user25 It's not.

Comment: yes, it is. if you have more than one controller then you have to add navigation controller

Comment: it showing me condition of iOS 13 ?? how can I do for iOS 12 ? Thank You.

Comment: Thanks @akashivskyy for the answer. Just wanted to add one thing if anyone wants to push the view controller from the navigation controller then the one could replace the last line i.e. `self.present(vc, animated: true)` by this line `self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)`

Answer (score 45):

For people using [@akashivskyy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24036067/2664437) to instantiate `UIViewController` and are having the exception:

> fatal error: use of unimplemented initializer 'init(coder:)' for class

**Quick tip:**

Manually implement `required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` at your destination `UIViewController` that you are trying to instantiate

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```

If you need more description please refer to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24036393/fatal-error-use-of-unimplemented-initializer-initcoder-for-class/24036440#24036440)

Comment: If you want to use custom initiator you can just call the super with  super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil) and the whew will load fine or do call it with the name of them NIB file.

Comment: @user1700737 I am instantiating the viewController referring to storyboard, which executes initWithCoder, not initWithNib. Refer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24036393/fatal-error-use-of-unimplemented-initializer-initcoder-for-class/24036440#24036440

Comment: Hi Friends, i am facing some different issue, This code run on simulator not on my ipad2 which having iOS v7.1.2. If you dont mind help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: @Indra you need to ask another question on stack, give me the link Ill be happy to help you!

Comment: On Swift 1.2 you must make `init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!)` "required". So now you have to write the following: `required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!)`

Answer (score 20):

[This link has both the implementations:](http://sketchytech.blogspot.sg/2012/11/instantiate-view-controller-using.html)

Swift:

```
let viewController:UIViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController") as UIViewController
self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Objective C

```
UIViewController *viewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];
```

[This link has code for initiating viewcontroller in the same storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25914744/swift-instantiateviewcontrollerwithidentifier)

```
/*
 Helper to Switch the View based on StoryBoard
 @param StoryBoard ID  as String
*/
func switchToViewController(identifier: String) {
    let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(identifier) as! UIViewController
    self.navigationController?.setViewControllers([viewController], animated: false)

}
```

Answer (score 15):

akashivskyy's answer works just fine! But, in case you have some trouble returning from the presented view controller, this alternative can be helpful. It worked for me!

Swift:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MyStoryboardName", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("someViewController") as! UIViewController
// Alternative way to present the new view controller
self.navigationController?.showViewController(vc, sender: nil)
```

Obj-C:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MyStoryboardName" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"someViewController"];
[self.navigationController showViewController:vc sender:nil];
```

Answer (score 14):

Swift 4.2 updated code is

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "StoryboardNameHere", bundle: nil)
let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewControllerNameHere")
self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 7):

```
// "Main" is name of .storybord file "
let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
// "MiniGameView" is the ID given to the ViewController in the interfacebuilder
// MiniGameViewController is the CLASS name of the ViewController.swift file acosiated to the ViewController
var setViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MiniGameView") as MiniGameViewController
var rootViewController = self.window!.rootViewController
rootViewController?.presentViewController(setViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

This worked fine for me when i put it in AppDelegate

Answer (score 7):

If you want to present it modally, you should have something like bellow:

```
let vc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("YourViewControllerID")
self.showDetailViewController(vc as! YourViewControllerClassName, sender: self)
```

Answer (score 7):

I would like to suggest a much cleaner way. This will be useful when we have multiple storyboards

**1.Create a structure with all your storyboards**

```
struct Storyboard {
      static let main = "Main"
      static let login = "login"
      static let profile = "profile" 
      static let home = "home"
    }
```

**2. Create a UIStoryboard extension like this**

```
extension UIStoryboard {
  @nonobjc class var main: UIStoryboard {
    return UIStoryboard(name: Storyboard.main, bundle: nil)
  }
  @nonobjc class var journey: UIStoryboard {
    return UIStoryboard(name: Storyboard.login, bundle: nil)
  }
  @nonobjc class var quiz: UIStoryboard {
    return UIStoryboard(name: Storyboard.profile, bundle: nil)
  }
  @nonobjc class var home: UIStoryboard {
    return UIStoryboard(name: Storyboard.home, bundle: nil)
  }
}
```

Give the storyboard identifier as the class name, and use the below code to instantiate

```
let loginVc = UIStoryboard.login.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "\(LoginViewController.self)") as! LoginViewController
```

Comment: Whats @nonobjc for ?

Comment: @StackRunner this will not be available to objective c

Answer (score 5):

No matter what I tried, it just wouldn't work for me - no errors, but no new view controller on my screen either. Don't know why, but wrapping it in timeout function finally made it work:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.0) {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabletViewController")
    self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Interesting. No async dispatch is needed usually unless the code is executed on a background thread

Answer (score 3):

Swift 3
[image: Storyboard]

```
let settingStoryboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "SettingViewController", bundle: nil)
let settingVC = settingStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SettingViewController") as! SettingViewController
self.present(settingVC, animated: true, completion: {

})
```

Answer (score 3):

Swift 4:

```
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let yourVC: YourVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "YourVC") as! YourVC
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a Viewcontroller not using any storyboard/Xib, you can push to this particular VC like below call :

```
 let vcInstance : UIViewController   = yourViewController()
 self.present(vcInstance, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: I get this: "cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers".

Comment: the outlets and other relationships made by the storyboard are lost

Answer (score 2):

Swift 5

```
let vc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CVIdentifier")
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old thread, but I think the current solution (using hardcoded string identifier for given view controller) is very prone to errors.

I've created a build time script (which you [can access here](https://github.com/nadav96/compiler-friendly-storyboard-access)), which will create a compiler safe way for accessing and instantiating view controllers from all storyboard within the given project.

For example, view controller named **vc1** in **Main.storyboard** will be instantiated like so:

```
let vc: UIViewController = R.storyboard.Main.vc1^  // where the '^' character initialize the controller
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a library that will handle this much more easier with better syntax:

https://github.com/Jasperav/Storyboardable

Just change Storyboard.swift and let the `ViewControllers` conform to `Storyboardable`.

Answer (score 0):

```
guard let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "add") else { return }
        vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer. Explaining the underlying logic is more important than just giving the code. It helps the author and other readers fix this and similar issues themselves while giving them the clues to the knowledge they need to expand their programming skills.

Answer (score 0):

```
if let destinationVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DestinationVC") as? DestinationVC{
            let nav = self.navigationController
            //presenting
            nav?.present(destinationVC, animated: true, completion: {
                
            })
            //push
            nav?.pushViewController(destinationVC, animated: true)
        }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

I use this helper:

```swift
struct Storyboard<T: UIViewController> {
    
    static var storyboardName: String {
        return String(describing: T.self)
    }
    
    static var viewController: T {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        
        guard let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: Self.storyboardName) as? T else {
            fatalError("Could not get controller from Storyboard: \(Self.storyboardName)")
        }
        
        return vc
    }
}
```

Usage (Storyboard ID must match the UIViewController class name)

```swift
let myVC = Storyboard.viewController as MyViewController
```