# Swift instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier

Tags: ios, swift

Currently i have:
1. Initial ViewController - AppStateViewController
2 .TabBarController - AuthorizedSessionViewController
3. ViewController - UnauthorizedSessionViewController

AppStateViewController Code - https://gist.github.com/nspavlo/de7a03f80e57694a12ba

If I call switchToAuthorizedSessionViewController() and switchToUnauthorizedSessionViewController() in viewDidLoad() AuthorizedSessionViewController appears instead of UnauthorizedSessionViewController.

My gol is to load right controller on didFinishLaunchingWithOptions and change it when appState is changed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why you use switchToAuthorizedSessionViewController() in your 
switchToViewController() method:

```
func switchToViewController(identifier: String) {
    let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(identifier) as UIViewController
    self.navigationController?.setViewControllers([viewController], animated: false)
    **switchToAuthorizedSessionViewController()**
}
```

You will create an infinite loop with that, try this:

```
class AppStateViewController: UIViewController {
    var authorized: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            if authorized { 
                 switchToAuthorizedSessionViewController()
            } else {
                switchToUnauthorizedSessionViewController()
            }
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.authorized = false
    }

    func switchToAuthorizedSessionViewController() {
        let sessionViewControllerID = "AuthorizedSessionViewController"
        switchToViewController(sessionViewControllerID)
    }

    func switchToUnauthorizedSessionViewController() {
        let sessionViewControllerID = "UnauthorizedSessionViewController"
        switchToViewController(sessionViewControllerID)
    }

    func switchToViewController(identifier: String) {
    let viewController =self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(identifier) as UIViewController
        self.navigationController?.setViewControllers([viewController], animated: false)
    }
}
```

with this you will be observing the property **authorized** and each time you change it, it will call the correct method.