# perfrmSegueWithIdentifier() not working in swift iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, segue

I don't get what I am doing wrong, I am trying to perform a push segue by an identifier so that I can move to other view-controller when an IF condition gets TRUE

the segue is always performed either I add this method : override func prepareForSegue()

```
     @IBAction func btnClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
    if(n.isEqualToString("mpc01") && p.isEqualToString("mpc01"))
               {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("login_to_dashboard", sender: nil)
               }
               else{
                println("no data retrieved")
                }
    }
 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "login_to_dashboard" {
           // let secondViewController = segue.destinationViewController as VC_dashboard
            println("performed segue")
        }
        else{
        println("recieved other command")
        }
    }
```

my ViewController storyboard ID : SID_login

my SecondViewController storyboard ID : SID_dashboard

my Push Segue ID : login_to_dashboard

I want to perform segue by its ID only , not directly

Comment: have you checked is your if condition is true?

Comment: yes i have checked it,its TRUE

Comment: I think you need to change the if condition in prepareforsegue method to
    if (segue.identifier == "login_to_dashboard") {
        //println("performed segue")
    }

Comment: see the answer i posted

Comment: create  segue from view controller to other view controller rather a button to view-controller if you do so it wont check condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry I am actually a beginner to xcode Swift , the question I asked was totally different to my segue issue. I actually created a segue directly from the button insteads of the first responser , thats why it always resulted to segue to another view-controller

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the control when you use `- (void)performSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender`. Instead, you can have control to trigger the segue or not by using this: `- (BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender`

The `prepareForSegue` just let you doing some custom works before triggering.

Comment: I replaced 'performSegueWithIdentifier()' with 'shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier()' but still result is **same ** . It just jumps to second view controller without concerning the IF-ELSE . I want to stop it going that way

Answer (score 0):

In  prepareForSegue method you are checking if `segue.identifier != "login_to_dashboard"`, I think you need to change it to == to perform segue.

```
@IBAction func btnClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
        if(n.isEqualToString("mpc01") && p.isEqualToString("mpc01"))
        {
          self.performSegueWithIdentifier("login_to_dashboard", sender: nil)
        }
        else {
               println("no data retrieved")
        }
     }

     override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
            if (segue.identifier == "login_to_dashboard") {
                let secondViewController = segue.destinationViewController as SecondViewController
                println("performed segue")
            }
            else{
            println("recieved other command")
            }
        }
```

Comment: yes that was my mistake I admit , but I changed the condition , still no difference .

Comment: I created a segue from a button to view controller , is that an issue ?

Comment: what is VC_dashboard, if you have created segue from button then you don't need to do it through code

Comment: I you want to use code then create manual segue from ViewController to SecondViewController then call self.performSegueWithIdentifier in btnClicked method

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26189588/move-to-another-viewcontroller I referred to this when I perform a segue

Comment: I created a manual segue and removed the segue I did from button to other viewcontroller, the condition started working now , but still when condition is TRUE it does not go to other view controller

Comment: is your first view controller embed in NavigationController if you are using push segue?

Comment: let secondViewController = segue.destinationViewController as SecondViewController is commented in your prepareForSegue method

Comment: yes you are right I am using embedded navigation controller for push segue

Answer (score 0):

You should use this method instead

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
         if segue.identifier == "login_to_dashboard" {
              return true
         }
         else{
              return false
         }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is very strange but since segue inherited from NSObject you can try:

```
    if(segue.valueForKey("_identifier") as String == "login_to_dashboard"){
        var targetController:VC_dashboard = segue.destinationViewController as VC_dashboard
        targetController.doSomthing()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I did the mistake , solution to my question is to create a segue from view controller to other view controller rather a button to view-controller