# Objective-C to Swift Navigation not working

Tags: uitableview, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I'm translating some code from Objective-C to Swift, but something isn't working. The code below is supposed to switch views and pass a String, however, nothing happens when a cell is tapped. I've embedded both ViewControllers with a NavigationViewController in Storyboard.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        var dvc : TemplateViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TemplateViewController") as TemplateViewController
        dvc.tweet = self.templateList?.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as NSString
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(dvc, animated: true)

}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want the action to happen when the cell is *deselected* rather than *selected*?  Look at the name if the method you've implemented v

Comment: ^ Yep that's right! Mindlessly used autofill

Comment: Have you checked `dvc` and `self.navigationController` aren't `null`?

Comment: @user3330259 did fixing the method name fix the problem?  If so Abizem may need to promote his comment to an answer so you can accept it.

Answer (score -1):

You need to explicitly write some methods in your TemplateViewController. Follow this SO answer
[Instantiate and Present a viewController in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24035984/instantiate-and-present-a-viewcontroller-in-swift)

Comment: He's got all the relevant parts of that in his example attempt.  The most likely culprits are in the comments to his question.