# Swift Changing views

Tags: swift

I've made an app for Apple Watch ("Brain Trainer For Apple Watch") that uses the following code:

`pushControllerWithName("SumsInterfaceController", context: type)`

I wanted to know if there's similar code to this for the iPhone version of Swift?

Answer (score 0):

For Navigation Controller

```
navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
```

For more info check [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/).

For Segue check [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIViewController) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27604192/ios-how-to-segue-programmatically-using-swift).

Comment: When I try to use that (see code) it gives me an error saying:  use of unsolved identifer 'pushViewController'   func segue(type:String) {
        
        
        pushViewController(SumsViewController, animated: true)
        
        
    }

Answer (score 0):

## For UIViewController

```
self.presentViewController(viewControllerToPresent: UIViewController, animated flag: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)?)

self.performSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String?, sender: AnyObject?)
```

## For UINavigationController: UIViewController

```
self.pushViewController(viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool)
```

---

## Dismiss UIViewController

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(flag: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)?)
```

## Dismiss UINavigationController: UIViewController

```
self.popViewControllerAnimated(animated: Bool)
self.popToViewController(viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool)
self.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(animated: Bool)
```