# Make each item in the tabel view clickable to perform action - Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview

i am pretty new to ios development. I have a table view with 2 Sections

TableView:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate{
var people = ["ABC","PQR","LMN"]
var languages = ["Android","Java","C++",".Net"]


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 2
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if section==0
    {return people.count}
    else
    {return languages.count
    }
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    if indexPath.section==0{
        cell.textLabel?.text = people[indexPath.row]
    }
    else{
        cell.textLabel?.text = languages[indexPath.row]

    }
    return cell
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    if section==0{
        title="Names"
    }
    else{
        title="Languages"
    }
    return title
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
}
 }
```

I want make each item in the table view clickable. That is when an item from the table view is clicked a new corresponding table view opens. Can someone help me with it ?

Comment: did you mean to navigate on click of cell in tableview?

Comment: Just incorporate what you require in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` function, based on the indexPath...

Comment: You want something like on click of `Language` you want to show list of language. Am i right?

Comment: @NiravDoctorwala yes that what i mean

Comment: @JigarTarsariya yes very correct

Comment: Try to search on google for `expandable tableview`, you will get your answer.

Comment: If you simply want to navigate on cell click then you can directly navigate via navigation controller on other view but if you want to expand table by clicking upon cell then you should have to try something extra with third party

Comment: @JigarTarsariya i want to open a new table view when a cell is Clicked. For example if "ABC" is clicked it navigates to a new table view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need if a if/switch statement in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` section. For example :

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        //do something
    }
    else if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        //do something else
    }
}
```

According the fact you want a new table view after click, I think you should perform a segue to present a new view controller. See here : [How to segue programmatically using swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27604192/ios-how-to-segue-programmatically-using-swift)

Comment: Thanks. But what do i write in the if statement. Like how do i navigate to the new table view?

Comment: That's the reason why I added a link for you on how to perform segues. You need to have your other tableviews in storyboard, give them a unique identifier, then use performSegueWithIdentifier with different identifier in if statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve navigation on other controller like this,

First you need to embed Navigation controller with your view so you can navigate easily.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) 
{
    if (indexPath.row == 0) 
    {

         let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("AddVC") as! addRecordViewController 
         self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
    else
    {
       // Navigate on other view
    }
}
```

Hope this will help.