# How to segue to view controller on panGesture

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I'm trying to segue to a view controller. the segue's identifier is "Orange" (the other view controller is just an orange view). The view controller is segued through storyboard and connected to an image view in my main view controller.
I want to trigger this with a pan gesture recognizer. So when a pan is detected, it just segues to the view controller.

This is my attempt:

```
@IBOutlet var panGesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer!

@IBAction func onPan(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    if panGesture.state == .Ended {
        print("panned")
    performSegueWithIdentifier("Orange", sender: sender)
    }
}
```

However, this is not working. I know it does detect the pan, but it doesn't perform the segue.

I read how to present the segue from [IOS - How to segue programmatically using swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27604192/ios-how-to-segue-programmatically-using-swift)

Comment: `if panGesture.state == .Ended` is working?

Comment: @Mr.UB Yes, I get panned printed out.

Comment: where you register panGesture with the action onPan?

Comment: try putting `self` like `self.performSegue...`, wild guess.

Comment: self. performSegueWithIdentifier("Orange", sender: sender)

Comment: no luck @AbdulRehmanWarraich

Comment: Is your panGesture is working fine?

Comment: @AbdulRehmanWarraich yes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try presenting ViewController's by instantiation: -

- Make sure you have a navigation Controller embed in your First VC
- **Giving your ViewController** a StoryBoardID :- Select the `ViewController` in your storyboard which you want to present -> *Identity Inspector* -> *StoryBoard ID* Give your VC a storyboard ID lets say : *"vc2SceneVC_ID"*
- Instantiate and push the VC like this:-

  ```
  @IBAction func onPan(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

  if panGesture.state == .Ended {
  print("panned")

   let vc2Scene = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("vc2SceneVC_ID") as! VC2
   self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc2Scene, animated: true)

  }
  ```

Apple Documentation for  **Navigation Controller** :- [UINavigationController Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/)

PS:- Prefer instantiating the navigating through ViewControllers with instantiation rather `performSegueWithIdentifier("Orange", sender: sender)`
Because this way you get to transfer data back-forth those viewControllers, also it prevents Memory Leaks in most cases.

Comment: Thanks! that works, but any idea why I have to embed in a Navigation Controller?

Comment: Navigation Controller is like a shuttle cock holder (open at both top and bottom) , you can push and pop a VC , but VC needs to know where it is in the index, basically A navigation controller will maintain the stack of view controllers.

Comment: @Marcel You don't have to use Navigation controller to do that

Comment: @AbdulRehmanWarraich then how are you going to push or pop a VC from a view hierarchy?

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: Control+Click from the first ViewController (where is the View Controller lab is shown) and drag to the second ViewController
[image]

step 2 :select the type of segue
 [image]

step 3:select the segue and set the identifier
[image]

and where you need to perform the segue just call   `self.performSegueWithIdentifier("test", sender: nil)`

sorry for bad English

Comment: In your case call the segue after    print("panned")

Comment: This is nothing different than what OP posted. Please read the question clearly before you post an answer.:)

Comment: @Dravidian Ok Thank's for your Correction.

Answer (score 1):

`Orange` must be the identifier of your segue in the storyboard and not the view controller identifier.

If your segue identifier is set properly try testing if your gesture callback is in the main thread.

*Let me know in the comments you have problems.*

Comment: Apologies for my bad wording, the Segue's identifier is "Orange"

Comment: @Marcel try setting nil in the sender, or self