# Can't programmatically trigger segue in SpriteKit, using Xcode 8 and Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit, segue

I'm making a game in Xcode 8 using SpriteKit and have been having a very difficult time programmatically triggering a segue.  I have gone into "Main.storyboard" and made a segue between my "GameViewController" and "MenuViewController" given it the identifier "toMenu".

**Failed Attempt #1**

Within my GameScene.swift file I have added the following code to the update function.

```
override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    // Called before each frame is rendered

    if gameIsRunning == false{
        score = 0
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "toMenu", sender: self)
    }
    }
```

My goal is for the segue to trigger whenever gameIsRunning is false.  However, I got the following error:

```
Use of unresolved identifier 'performSegue'
```

This is odd because performSegue is a declaration according to the [API Reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621413-performsegue).

**Failed Attempt #2**

I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27604411/7805980) by putting the following code into "GameScene.swift"

```
override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    // Called before each frame is rendered

    if gameIsRunning == false{
        score = 0
        GameScene(MenuViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

and I got this error:

```
Type of expression is ambiguous without more context
```

**Failed Attempt #3**

I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39198861/7805980) very confusing but I following along anyways.  I had already done step 1, so as stated in step 2, I put the following code at the bottom of "GameViewController.swift"

```
func goToDifferentView() {

self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toMenu", sender: self)

}
```

and didn't get an error! Then I added this code to "GameViewController.swift" as instructed in step 3 of the solution

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(goToDifferentView), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "toMenu"), object: nil)
```

Then I did step 4 of the solution so I put the following code into "MenuViewController.swift"

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NotificationCenter.default.post(NSNotification(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "toMenu"), object: nil) as Notification)
```

I then put the following code into my "GameScene.swift" file to actually call the function.

```
    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    // Called before each frame is rendered

    if gameIsRunning == false{
        score = 0
        GameViewController().goToDifferentView()
    }
```

I then ran my game on my iPhone and everything went well until I get to the part of the game where gameIsRunning turns to false.  Instead of the segue doing its thing, I got the following error:

```
Thread 1: Signal SIGABRT
```

I've gotten this error several times and it's always been that I have something hooked up incorrectly in "Main.storyboard". However, this an incredibly simple game and everything looks normal.  I also didn't get this error until adding the code that I just showed you.  I have confirmed several times that the segue has the identifier "toMenu".  I have absolutely no clue why the segue won't work and why my Attemp #3 is causing a SIGABRT error.

Comment: What kind of segue is it?

Comment: @GlennRay It's kind is 'Show (e.g. Push)' and it is a 'Storyboard Segue'.  I'm not sure how to get any additional details about it.

Comment: Great first question. Tip: if you want to use bold, use double star either side of a piece of text, it's easier to type (and easier to re-edit) than HTML. If you want to format an inline piece of code in a paragraph, `use a backtick` either side.

Comment: Shouldn't the post notification statement be in the `if gameIsRunning...` block?

Comment: @0x141E I tried moving the `NotificationCenter.default.post(NSNotification(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "toMenu"), object: nil) as Notification)' from step 4 of failed solution #3 from the viewDidLoad() in MenuViewController.swift into the 'if gameIsRunning == false' part of the update function in GameScene.sks.  I still got a SIGABRT error.

Comment: The `if` and `post` statements shouldn't be in the `update` method. I suggest you move it to where `gameIsRunning` is set to `false` or define a computed property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are trying to trigger this segue in the update() function, it's being called many times per second.  Try the following code and it should work.

```
override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
// Called before each frame is rendered

if gameIsRunning == false{
    score = 0
    gameIsRunning = true
   NotificationCenter.default.post(NSNotification(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "toMenu"), object: nil) as Notification)
}
```

If you were to place `print("update")` in your `if` statement you would see what I mean.  Setting the `gameIsRunning` bool to true inside your if will insure it only gets called once.