# How to perform segue to Different Controllers in UICollectionVIew

Tags: swift3

[image]I want to segue to different controllers based on selection in UICollectionView :

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

```
    if indexPath.item == 0 && indexPath.section == 0 {

    print ("Item 0 and section 0 selected")

        Perform Segue to Controller1 


    } else if (indexPath.item == 1 && indexPath.section == 0 ){

        ----> Perform Segue to Controller 2 


        print ("Item 1 and section 0 selected")
    } else {
        print("Not selected ")
    }



}
```

Based on selection in Collection View it should segue to Different UiCollectionView Controllers

```
Tried this command
```

self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Selection1", sender: self)

But it errored out :
 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with identifier ProductCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

What is the best way to perform this kind of Segue ?
Please advise

Thanks

Comment: Ummm... `performSegueWithIdentifier: sender:`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IOS - How to segue programmatically using swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27604192/ios-how-to-segue-programmatically-using-swift)

Comment: HI ,  i tried using the option given in the above link  but I Got this error , 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with identifier ProductCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

Comment: self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Selection1", sender: self)  --Tried this command

Answer (score 0):

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

```
    if indexPath.item == 0 && indexPath.section == 0 {




        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Selection1", sender: self)







    } else if (indexPath.item == 1 && indexPath.section == 0 ){


     self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Selection2", sender: self)

        print ("Item 1 and section 0 selected")
    } else {
        print("Not selected ")
    }



}
```

Also in order to get rid of error i had to update the Identifier in Collection Reusable View [image]