# SWIFT 4 - Open UICollectionView by clicking on an item of UITableView

Tags: swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have:

- a TableViewController with several users
- a UICollectionViewController (a Chat)

I am trying to open the UICollectionViewController, when the User is clicking on one user in the TableViewController. The TableViewController should disappear, the UICollectionViewController (my Chat) should appear.

I am googling and stackoverflowing for 10 hours, but now im just desperated.

I have the following code in my TableViewController with all the users inside:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: 
IndexPath)
{
let destination = MainChatViewController()
present(destination, animated: true)
}
```

I am getting the error: Thread 1: signal SIGABRT error, and I have NO idea why. I appreaciate any help - thank you

George

Comment: I think you need to use `self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Identifier") as! MainChatViewController` method instead of using `MainChatViewController()`

Comment: Have you set the collection view layout?

Comment: Can you post the error message from your logs?

Comment: @Paulo: I am fairly new to SWIFT, if you mean something like addSubViews (in my function setupComponents()), then yes.

Comment: @Rugmangathan: nsinvalidArgumentException, reason: UICollectionView must be initialized with a non-nil layout parameter

Comment: Are you using storyboards to create your views, or are you doing it programmatically?

Comment: @Paulo: Mainly storyboard, the UICollectionView programmatically! Thanks for your help

Comment: So, MainChatViewController is a UIViewController, with a collection view added?

Comment: @Paulo. No. My MainChatViewController is a UICollectionViewController, in which I have Code to create a button and a textfield, constraints. I am using a function to create all items (e. g. let containerView = UIView(), view.addSubview(containerView)

Comment: Okay, so if you are using storyboards, I suggest you look at  this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43328838/how-to-perform-segue-to-different-controllers-in-uicollectionview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are definitely wanting to create your `UICollectionViewController` 100% programmatically like you show in your example you're going to have to program in all of the UI work, including implementing the `loadView` function.

I know some people are anti-Storyboard, but I feel you are creating unnecessary work when you could just lay out your viewController in storyboard, give it a Storyboard ID (for example "ChatViewController"), and in your tableView's `didSelect` method say:

```
let chatVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ChatViewController") as! MainChatViewController
self.present(chatVC, animated: true)
```

Comment: I like this answer, for its simplicity and the users use of storyboards. Better than mine :)

Comment: Thank you - just to clarify: If i use your solution, I get a "THREAD 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x102*************) Error in my function which creates the textfield etc. Is this caused, because i create the objects programmicatally?

Comment: I have no way of knowing without seeing a lot more context.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/7HBIz Sorry for the quality. I gave my controller the correct storyboard ID!

Comment: That likely means that your optional tabBarController is in fact nil.  You are crashing because you're force unwrapping it.  You also don't need to constrain anything to the tabBarController - just constrain it to the viewController's `view` property and that'll be automatically adjusted to account for a tabBar.

Comment: You are correct. When I exclude "containView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.BottomAnchor, constant: -(1) * (self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.size.height)!).isActive = true", it works! How can I access to my tabBar as well? Its missing, and i got it why, now the question is how to implement it as well as the collectionviewcontroller

Comment: Btw - when i dont constraint the tabBar height, my textfield will be on the bottom on my screen, hided by the tabBar

Answer (score 0):

So, from what I can tell, you have a `UICollectionViewController` called MainChatViewController.

Your error message is occurring because a collection view requires a layout parameter when it is initialized. I wouldn’t say standard, but most use the flow layout

```
let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
let destination = MainChatViewController(collectionViewLayout: layout)
present(destination, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Now this is not to say it is the only way of doing it, and I am sure that there are brighter people that can offer many other opinions.

Comment: Hey - "Argument labels (layout:" do not match any available overloads")

Comment: Sorry it should be collectionViewLayout instead of layout