# Creating a segue programmatically without a storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboardsegue

Trying to create a segue for my register button which is going to send a user to a page that will allow them to register in my database.

Usually, I make a button and a target for my button which performs some action through a function.

**Can we make this function segue** `PROGRAMMATICALLY` **mind you I haven't used storyboards at all?**

**Code Snippet:**

```
 lazy var registerButton: UIButton = {

    let rButton = UIButton(type: .system)

     rButton.frame = CGRect(x: 210, y: 600, width: 100, height: 50)

    rButton.setTitle("REGISTER", for: .normal)
    rButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    rButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    rButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
    rButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)

    rButton.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    rButton.layer.borderWidth = 2

    rButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(regSegue), for: .touchUpInside)

    return rButton
}()

// will segue for me
func regSegue(){

}
```

Comment: any help is appreciated

Comment: @Idan possibly not

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IOS - How to segue programmatically using swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27604192/ios-how-to-segue-programmatically-using-swift)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you meant a `ViewController` by the word ***page***. So initialize your `ViewController` inside your `func regSegue(){...}` and present it using `present(_:animated:completion:)` method.

Example:

```
func regSegue(){
    let page = PageViewController()
    present(page, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: how do i do that

Comment: one more question can i add inputContainer views and button to this new page

Comment: figured it out !

Comment: how do you change the color of the background to whtie

Comment: You need to post another question for other queries. But first try searching in _Stack Overflow_ or _google search_. You will find lots of questions and answer regarding ___how to change background color___.

Comment: thats a waste of a question i tired to change it, it goes whtie than right back to black

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this easily without a storyboard.First, you need to initialize the viewcontroller which you need to show.Then present the view controller.

```
 let vc: MyViewController = MyViewController()
 self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```