# How to move from one view controller to another automatically?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I want to switch to another view controller after my app is loaded after some seconds, how to do that ?

Comment: [How to segue programmatically using swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27604192/ios-how-to-segue-programmatically-using-swift) may also be useful.

Comment: Please show what you have done until, and there are so many questions related to navigation from one view to another so let us know what you have tried yet so we can help you further.

Comment: i have creater 2nd view controller  with id as SecondViewController , i need to move to second view controller after some timeframe(1 sec), that is after the app is loaded in 1st view controller,1st view controller is initial view controller

Answer (score 3):

**Try this**

You can perform segue, navigate and present next view controller in the block

Add this in `ViewDidLoad` , `ViewWillAppear`

```
 DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2, execute: {
      self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "leadingToTutorial", sender: self)
 })
```

Comment: I am getting SIGABRT error, i checked my viewcontroller identifier name its correct

Comment: can you explain with more code?

Comment: import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2, execute: {
      self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController", sender: self)
 }) 
        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41887007/5461400 check this

Comment: thank you it worked

Answer (score 2):

In **Swift 3.0,** you used Time to move one **ViewController** to second **ViewController**. here I have create code so watch it.

import UIKit

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var gameTimer: Timer! //Timer object

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        gameTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.5, target: self, selector: #selector(timeaction), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    }

    //Timer action
    func timeaction(){

        //code for move next VC
        let secondVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController") as! SecondViewController
                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondVC, animated: true)
        gameTimer.invalidate()//after that timer invalid

    }
}
```

I hope It's work.

Comment: this works in swift 4 as well.

Comment: yeah of cource @R.Mohan

Answer (score 0):

when viewDidLoad Method of your First ViewControllers will Execute , you can define there your code For Move to Another ViewController , For Some Second delay you can use

**For Delay of Some Seconds**

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
    // your code here For Pushing to Another Screen
}
```

here you can define how much time you want as a delay , in example i mentioned 0.1 , you can define as per your requirements

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Timer`

```
Class name {
  private var timer: Timer?

  fun viewDidLoad() {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5, target: self, selector: #selector(yourMethod), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

  }

  objc func yourMethod() {
   performSegue(withIdentifier:Sender:)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your view's `viewDidLoad()` method you can add following line at the end of the method

```
[self performSelector:@selector(goNext:)withObject:nil afterDelay:5.0];
```

And inside `goNext:` method you can add

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

to perform navigation and go to next view.

Comment: Take a careful look at the tags.