# UIStoryboard controller class as base class

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

I have a base `UIViewController` called `BaseController` and it is invoked via a `segue` in my `storyboard`. Now I have two subclasses of this baseController - `Subclass1` and `Subclass2`. I want to invoke `SubBaseController1` or `SubBaseController2` depending on the target when the `segue` gets triggered. How do I instantiate `SubBaseController1` in `target1` or `SubBaseController2` in `target` 2 when the `segue` gets invoked?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IOS - How to segue programmatically using swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27604192/ios-how-to-segue-programmatically-using-swift)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two way:

1. Use two different segues. Add identifiers for both, similar to this picture [image: Segue Id] and then call this code to open the correct screen

```swift
performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue1", sender: nil)
```

2. Don't create any segue, but add `storyboardId` to view controller, similar to this:
   [image: Adding storyboardId]
   and use this code to init and show view controller:

```swift
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
let viewController1 = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "viewController1")
present(viewController1, animated: true)
```

I will recommend the second way as it gives you more control over the displaying process.