# reference a storyboard from inside a framework

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboard, ios-frameworks

I created a framework and and imported it to another project.

In the framework i also created a storyboard

But when i try to get a reference to this storyboard it throws an exception:

> **Assertion failure in -[UIStoryboard initWithBundle:storyboardFileName:identifierToNibNameMap:designatedEntryPointIdentifier:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3347.44/UIStoryboard.m:52
>       2015-06-21 14:24:35.340 TestProject[2923:105798]**

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid parameter not satisfying: nibNameMap != nil'
```

This is the code for loading the storyboard:

```
let frameworkBundle = NSBundle(identifier: "a.b.c") // that work 
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "storyBoardIdentifyer", bundle: frameworkBundle)
```

In my framework i see the storyboard file in the directory and try to reference it by its name and its defined storyBoardIdentifyer with no luck

Am i missing something?

Comment: Check this anser in stack overflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24035984/instantiate-and-present-a-viewcontroller-in-swift