# After instantiating TableViewController subclass programmatically, its outlets are nil

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, null, uitextfield

After instantiating the `EditCountsTableViewCell` programmatically its outlets return nil when accessed, and I therefore cannot edit the cells. The cells behave normally when instantiated with the Storyboard.

```
@IBAction func countNameChanged(sender: AnyObject) {

    let textField = sender as! UITextField
    let text = textField.text

    let superview = textField.superview!
    let cell = superview.superview as! EditCountsTableViewCell
    let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForCell(cell)
    let row = indexPath?.row

    var newCell = EditCountsTableViewCell() //Instantiate Cell Programatically

    println(newCell)

    println(newCell.countName) //nil

    if let name = newCell.countName{

        name.text = text

    }

    if let value = newCell.countValue{

        value.text = cell.countValue.text

    }

    tableViewContents[row!] = newCell

}
```

`EditCountsTableViewCell` Class:

```
import UIKit

class EditCountsTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var countName: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var countValue: UITextField!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this way of initialization?

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MyStoryboardName", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("someViewController") as! UIViewController
```

[(Source)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24036067/2177402)

Comment: I'm kind of new to this, how would instantiating the view controller programmatically help?

Comment: Usually if your desired view controller is in a different storyboard you use code to instantiate that, other than that try to use segue's. Less code = less bugs

Comment: But how would this help to instantiate a `TableViewCell`?

Comment: This would instantiate the `tableView` as if you accessed it from the storyboard, so the system would take care of instantiating all of its _dependents_

Answer (score 0):

You want to get a EditCountsTableViewCell variable programatically, but your cell is inited from storyboard, so you should get it from storyboard.

Comment: So is there a way to properly instantiate an `EditCountsTableViewCell` programmatically?

Comment: You just want to edit the cell, why didn't you use     func cellForRowAtIndexPath(_ indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell?  to  get the cell?

Comment: I'm not just editing the cell, I am trying to keep a separate array of all of the cells in the tableview, I cannot find a way to simply access this from the `TableView` class