# Navbar issues, swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

1) https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAVNn.jpg

3) https://i.stack.imgur.com/9z0Ai.png

Hi,

Here I have 3 screenshots, the 1st one is of snapchat nav bar, 2 and 3 are of my simulator nav bar.

Basiclly I would like to achieve the same similar nav bar as snapchats, kind of fixed? so when you scroll it move with the screen?! and has no animation like mine does in pic 2-3.

As you can see in my the navbar items/title changes before you have even swiped across...

Is there any way of fixing that with code? and do you have any idea what the coee it for setting the second view controller as 1st when apps launched? I know how to do it with a scroll view, but not with a pageviewcontroller...

p.s as I cannot add more than two links I shall add screenshot n°2 and the shot of my code below.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: screenshot 2 : http://i.stack.imgur.com/vWLum.png

Comment: code: http://i.stack.imgur.com/SQyEV.png     ;      http://i.stack.imgur.com/fC4WI.png

Comment: Please add code to your question as text rather than posting screenshots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to achieve is not at all achieved by this UISwipeViewController.

What you really want to use is a plain UIPageViewControler!
Have every single one of those child view controller setup their own navigation bar (which is exactly what SnapChat does).

The **UISwipeViewController** is a hybrid of page view controller and navigation controller. If you don't want navigation bar for all of the pages, then just use a page view controller.

Does it make sense?

**UPDATE:** check this out: https://github.com/Peyman-Tutorials-SourceCodes/Swift-SnapChat-Like-Navigation

Comment: I'm lovin this! Ok well thanks alot, I'll try figure something out and see how far I get this time! I'll get it right sooner or later!

Comment: Should I follow this? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8bltsDG2ENQ

Comment: @Charles I created something similar, check it out. Link is in the answer

Comment: Absolutely fantastic! just what I wanted! and I gues its simple to enable vertical scrolling/bouncing ?

Comment: Yeah, use a scrollbar in the view controllers to get that bouncing effect.

Comment: Great, you have been amazingly helpful! do you know what code that needs using to set the second page to appear at app launch? I can't  figure it out..

Comment: Yeah, just change the order of the view controllers in the ViewController.swift

Comment: I mean so they are in the same order, but so the middle screen shows first..and you can scroll either right or left to the other views?

Comment: Exactly, perhaps you should look into UIPageViewController docs a bit. UIPageViewControllerDataSource has two methods that asks for left and right of each individual child view controller.

Comment: Got it, great thank you!

Comment: could you please have a quick look? im really struggling! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33967178/swift-search-data-not-loading