# Swift - Search data not loading

Tags: swift, parse-platform, uisearchcontroller

I'm trying to add a search feature to my app with Parse, I have wrote the code with a `UISearchController`, but for some reason when I load the app and try to search nothing works. My parse is all set up correctly, so there must be something wrong with my code!

Here it is:

```
import UIKit
import Parse
class SearchTableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating
{

    var searchResults = [String]()

    var resultSearchController = UISearchController()

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {super.viewDidLoad()
        self.resultSearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        self.resultSearchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        self.resultSearchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        self.resultSearchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.resultSearchController.searchBar

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }



    func query()
    {
        let query = PFQuery(className:"_User")
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (results: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error != nil {
                if let objects = results! as [PFObject]! {
                    for object in objects {
                        let userName = object.objectForKey("firstName") as! String
                        self.searchResults.append(userName)
                        self.tableView.reloadData()   //<-- must reloadData()
                    } } }
        }





    // MARK: - Table view data source
 func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int
    {
        return 1
    }

   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return searchResults.count
    }
  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = searchResults[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }



   func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController)
    {
        self.searchResults.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

        let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", searchController.searchBar.text!)
        let array = (self.searchResults as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)
        self.searchResults = array as! [String]

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first I don't think it's a good idea to filter directly from parse. It would be better to download everything from parse then you filter that data.

So your query function will now look like:

```
 func query()
{
   let query = PFQuery(className:"_User")
   query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (results: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if error != nil {
        if let objects = results! as [PFObject]! {
        for object in objects {
            let userName = object.["firstname"] as! String
            self.searchResults.append(userName)
           self.tableView.reloadData()   //<-- must reloadData()
        } } }
 }
```

**So now your array contains firstname of all users from parse**

> self.tableView.reloadData() should not be in the life cycle viewDidLoad(), and don't forget to call `query()` into viewDidLoad()

you should create another array to save the result from the filters.

The `numberOfRowsInSection()` method should have two options where the filter array returns filter objects from the search Bar  or just objects from parse.

And the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` should be also modified because you will return data from either from filter array or default array

I believed you should go trough this tutorial carefully to see how their filter code works [enter link description here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/76519/add-table-view-search-swift).

Comment: Hi @Lamour Thanks for your answer, I have tried the thing syou have mentioned, but still cannot get it to function.. I also found this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AXbxBYcj_vI what do you think could this work?

Comment: What is not working ? Or matter of fact you should try to comment out all the filter code then try to run the code to see if what you have is working

Comment: you should try your code without the filter part@Charles

Comment: Im guessing the filter is the func query bit you added? I have just tried that, it loads etc, and does everything apart from search?

Comment: I get two errors now, 1)  Type 'SearchTableViewController' does not conform to protocol 'UISearchResultsUpdating'

Comment: 2) func for cellForRowAtIndePpath : "Definition conflicts with previous value"

Comment: can you share this project. so i could help you for a bit while i have time ?

Comment: Do you want me to share the proj with you? so you can see?

Comment: yeah if you want to and also stop posting the same question on stackoverflow

Comment: sorry for the delay... try this link https://www.dropbox.com/sh/3qehgdk33kawbj8/AADjO62lr1jWuwfJtSPjZtVla?dl=0       if not download it from here: https://www.veasoftware.com/tutorials/2015/6/27/uisearchcontroller-in-swift-xcode-7-ios-9-tutorial and just add my code..

Comment: I got a friend to upload it to dropbox, but not sure if that'll work...best bet is gettign it from Veasoftware

Comment: go to stackoverfow chat look for this room "CheckerHelp"

Comment: I can't chat! you need more that 20 reputation