# Can't change rootViewController in Appdelegate?

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate, rootviewcontroller

I design a soft Pin.

You can put 4 numbers twice and it will be your code. When you finished code assignment. The view will present segue (kind: Present Modally) to show another viewController.

Due to convenient, I would like to reset the View controller.

The Best way I found on the stack overflow is to reset rootViewController in the Appdelegate
[Solution Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24035984/instantiate-and-present-a-viewcontroller-in-swift)

When I follow the steps, I got an error below :

[image]

The Console shows :

[image]

Maybe the problem is the design in my storyboard

The upper one is original viewController

[image]

Can anyone figure out what's wrong with my code?

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: check your view controller identifier ... is it `EnterPinViewController` or not

Comment: Is the title same as identifier in the storyboard ?

Comment: identifier is same as you are used in `instantiateviewcontrollerwithidentifier`

Comment: Instead of resetting the `rootViewController` you could simply dismiss your modal controller to go back to your initial PIN view.

Comment: Thanks guys!!! I fished it. Ya

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is from your Storyboard : you don't have a view controller with a StoryBoard ID `EnterPinViewController`.

Go to your Storyboard, select the controller and on side panel Utilities check the StoryBoard ID value.

Or change `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` parameter with the one matching the Storyboard Identifier of your view controller.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. I found the problem.

Answer (score 1):

1. Click on your controller in storyboard.
2. In right side panel go to identity Inspector (3rd button)
3. Set Storyboard ID to EnterPinViewController

You are all set to go further now!!