# Swift Prepare for segue interrupted by TabBarController

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I currently have a storyboard that has a tableview with my data, and I believe I correctly pass that data using the didSelectRowAtIndexPath and the prepareForSegue functions.
My problem is that when I select a certain cell my cast becomes incorrect because I have a tab bar controller holding my views to be displayed with this segued information.
I want my cast to be:

```
let destination = segue.destinationViewController as! DownloadViewController
```

But I am getting an error because the segue is going to the tab bar controller first. This error makes perfect sense to me but I am unsure how to get around it without getting rid of the tab bar controller completely. Here is a picture of my story board to help show the overall flow.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRtq3.jpg

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UITabBarController has an array that contains its connnected viewController, to access e.g. the first one try

```
let destination = (segue.destinationViewController as! UITabBarController).viewControllers?.first as! DownloadViewController
```

Comment: Thanks this is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using segue, you can use a modal presentation of your desired first tab for display if it works for you.

```
let displayFirstVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("newVC") as! UIViewController
self.presentViewController(displayFirstVC , animated: true, completion: nil)
```

When you instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier, you have to create a storyboard name for your FirstViewController with name newVC.

You would also need to replace UIViewController with the name you gave your view controller.

[image: tp://i.stack.imgur.com/6MMsy.png]

More details here. 
[Instantiate and Present a viewController in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24035984/instantiate-and-present-a-viewcontroller-in-swift)

Comment: Is there a way to pass information with this method? Similar to what prepare ForSegue does?