# Cocoapods: Not enough arguments provided; where is the input document to operate on?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

My simple cocoapod project has only 4 files (3 classes and 1 storyboard):

[image]

But I permanently have an issue like on the image below:

[image]

> Not enough arguments provided; where is the inout document to operate on?

What to do to eliminate it?

Comment: You can get the correct answer at there:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4422#event-442170157

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Remove PhotoGallery.storyboard file from the Compile Sources build phase and add to Copy Bundle Resources phase.

Comment: ok, I did it, but then do you know how to access my view controller from that storyboard? `UIStoryboard(name: "PhotoGallery", bundle: nil).instantiateInitialViewController()` doesnt work

Comment: Clean project, delete derived data. Recompile.

Comment: Ok, it compiles, but while running I try to access controller from mentioned storyboard, and actually I do not know how...

Comment: Maybe you should proceed as there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24035984/instantiate-and-present-a-viewcontroller-in-swift Also run pod install etc.

Comment: Are you sure your stroyboard has the name PhotoGallery and not main or something else?

Answer (score 3):

Remove PhotoGallery.storyboard file from Classes folder and move it to Assets folder. 
This solved my problem.