# How to add a UICollectionView to a container programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new to IOS development.

The followings are what I want to implement
- Have a two container in the main view
- In the first container, add a UICollectionView
- In the second container, add a UITableView

This is the code that I've done so far.

Main View:

```
class MainViewController:UIViewController {

let itemView:UIView = {
    let itemContainerView = UIView()
    itemContainerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
    let collectionView = CollectionViewController()
    itemContainerView.addSubview(collectionView.view)
    itemContainerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return itemContainerView
}()

let tableView:UIView = {
    let tableContainerView = UIView()
    tableContainerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
    tableContainerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return tableContainerView
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    view.addSubview(itemView)
    view.addSubview(tableView)
    setupItemView()
    setupTableView()
}

func setupItemView(){
    itemView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    itemView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    itemView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 2/3).isActive = true
    itemView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor).isActive = true
}

func setupTableView() {
    tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    tableView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: itemView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    tableView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1/3).isActive = true
    tableView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor).isActive = true
}
}
```

CollectionViewController:

```
class CollectionViewController:UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

let cellId = "CellId"
var colView: UICollectionView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 111, height: 111)

    colView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    colView.delegate   = self
    colView.dataSource = self
    colView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
    colView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    colView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.view.addSubview(colView)

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath)
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.brown
    return cell
}

}
```

I could see my main screen has two container but couldn't see 10 collection cells.

Could anyone advise me to the right direction? Thanks in advance.

**UPDATED**

When I set MainViewController as the initial view, it's properly working.
However, in my project, MainViewController is not the initial view.
The flow is;
1. User login
2. Dashboard with a button will appear
3. Clicking button will navigate the user to MainViewController.

Here's my Dashboard class

```
class DashboardController: UIViewController{

let orderBtn:UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 173/255, green: 184/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1)
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    button.setTitle("Select Item" , for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
    button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleOrderNavigation), for: .touchUpInside)
    return button
}()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    view.addSubview(orderBtn)
    setupOrderBtn()

}

func handleOrderNavigation() {
    let mainViewController= MainViewController()
    let mainViewNavController= UINavigationController(rootViewController: mainViewController)
    self.present(mainViewNavController, animated: false, completion: nil)
}
}
```

Comment: I doubt the collectionView has the correct frame in `viewDidLoad`. Use autolayout, or set the frame later. You also don't set the frame when you add the CollectionViewController to the `itemView`.

Comment: @JamesP How can i use autolayout to make the view fit into the superview(container)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is proper working. here is the output I got from your `collectionView` code work.

[image]

> Suggestion

1. Check view hierarchy of your UI and see is there is any collectionView present in your UI.
2. Ensure your methods are properly calling. Check it by adding break point.

> Edit

1. You declaration of `MainViewController` is wrong in button action.
2. Instead of present `MainViewController` use push to `MainViewController`
3. Be ensure your button action method is properly calling on button click.

Comment: If I set the MainView as the initial view, as you said, it's working properly. But when I navigate from another view to the MainView, I cannot see the cells.

Comment: @J.GS.Han Are you passing data from other VC to main VC?? Can you tell flow of your work. What actually you want in your UI/

Comment: I'm not passing any data at the moment. 
Flow is: 
Once user log in, the user will see the main dashboard. If the user clicks a button, user will be navigated to the MainView.

Comment: I've updated the question with the previous view class

Comment: @J.GS.Han 1st of all its `MainVC` not `MainView`, I am always get confused when you write so specify things correctly, because there is lots of difference in between them.

Comment: And keep in mind that if you resent any `VC` then you can not navigate to any other VC from that. So for navigate your VC first you have to come back then only you can navigate to any other VC.

Comment: i checked your first point as well :) Also thanks for letting me know the difference between present and push but not sure why it's still not presenting the cells :(...

Comment: @J.GS.Han [instantiate & present VC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24035984/instantiate-and-present-a-viewcontroller-in-swift) Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Try to call `reloadData` at some point after the view is loaded.