# Problems with presenting VC, the screen turns black

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

I am trying to present VC after user is logged in. But after login is successful the VC turns black. Demonstration what happens is [here](https://vimeo.com/222359186) and there are same images. I have found articles here on stackoverflow but any of them did not help me.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQXIF.png)[image][image][image][image]

Comment: `ALMainController()` is equal to `ALMainController.init` and NOT "ALMainController.initTheOneSetWithAllTheOutletsAndConstraintsInTheStoryboard". Check that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24035984/instantiate-and-present-a-viewcontroller-in-swift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code :

```
    let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc: ALMainController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ALMainController") as! ALMainController

    self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Or you can use this:

```
    let firstPage = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ALMainController")as! ALMainController
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate
    appDelegate?.window??.rootViewController = firstPage
```

Both should work.

And do not forget to write: "ALMainController" to your storyboard Id.

[image]

Let me know if it worked. :)

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is that you are just initialising the ALMainController class.

However, this will not load your view from the Storyboard. There are 2 ways to do that properly and present that controller.

1. In code by doing something like the following, given that this controller has an identifier like: "ALMainController"

`let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil) 
let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ALMainController")

self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)`

2. By creating a Segue in storyboard originating from the "Login controller" going towards the "ALMainController". You give that segue an identifier (EX: "goToMain") and call that in your code doing something like the following

`self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToMain", sender: self)`

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works, same as answer before yours. Appreciate your feedback a lot. Thanks.