# Tableview nil, but exist in storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have view controller that have tableView connected to it. I present controller like that :

(in previous controller):

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let vc = DetailCharacterViewController()
        let characterModel = (self.viewModel.arrValues[indexPath.row] as! CharacterListItem).correspondingCharacter
        let vm = DetailCharacterViewModel(m: characterModel)
        vc.viewModel = vm
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }
```

But when controller appears, it crashes when try to access tableView property, that is actually:

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
```

In debug i can see that it is nil. Why?

Comment: Because `let vc = DetailCharacterViewController()` is not calling the ViewController "in/linked with" the storyboard, it's creating a new one, but not the one in the Storyboard.

Comment: @Larme ok, how to fix it?

Comment: `vc` should be instantiated by its storyboard; check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32139127/5501940).

Comment: can you addlast line on first first line then try

Answer (score 1):

You can use segue and `func prepare` to make a transition between viewControllers.
Here is Apple documentation [Make transition between view controllers](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/UsingSegues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH15-SW1)