# How to open specific ViewController from TabBarController

Tags: ios, swift, navigationcontroller, tabbarcontroller

Sorry, if it is an essential question.

The scheme is the following:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWr4R.png)

I want the following:

1. User taps last Tab
2. User goes to some ViewController (different from ViewController, actually connected with last Tab)

How to do this (without using segue)?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Use [`instantiateViewController`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24036067/14351818)

Answer (score 0):

You can go with `instantiateViewController` with push when load your tab and push one viewController to another like below:

```
 let next = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "nextVC")as! nextVC
 self.navigationController?.pushViewController(next, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign ViewController in you UITabBarController

```
         let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        
        // create view controllers from storyboard
        // Make sure you set Storyboard ID for both the viewcontrollers in 
        // Interface Builder -> Identitiy Inspector -> Storyboard ID
        let clockViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ClockViewController")
        let stopWatchViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("StopWatchViewController")
        
        // Set up the Tab Bar Controller to have two tabs
        let tabBarController = UITabBarController()
        tabBarController.viewControllers = [clockViewController, stopWatchViewController]
        
        // Make the Tab Bar Controller the root view controller
        window?.rootViewController = tabBarController
```