# Cannot parse ephemeral key, how do I send the unmodified JSON

Tags: ios, swift, stripe-payments, exc-bad-access, init

**POST EDITED**

I have a `CheckoutViewController` that I copied from the Stripe git repository and I implemented it into my app. At first I was trying to setup the `STPPaymentContext` in a different vc but it was giving a bad access but now when I try to set it up in the Checkout vc, I get an assertion failure saying the JSON couldn't be parsed.

This is what I have in my `MyAPIClient` class:

```
class MyAPIClient: NSObject, STPCustomerEphemeralKeyProvider {


let baseURL = "https://us-central1-attend-41f12.cloudfunctions.net/createEphemeralKeys"


let ticketVC: TicketFormViewController = TicketFormViewController()


func createCustomerKey(withAPIVersion apiVersion: String, completion: @escaping STPJSONResponseCompletionBlock) {
    ticketVC.getUsersStripeCustomerID { (customerid) in
        if let id = customerid {
            let url = URL(string:self.baseURL)!
            var urlComponents = URLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false)!
            urlComponents.queryItems = [URLQueryItem(name: "api_version", value: apiVersion), URLQueryItem(name: "customer_id", value: id)]
            var request = URLRequest(url: urlComponents.url!)
            request.httpMethod = "POST"
            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
                guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
                      response.statusCode == 200,
                      let data = data,
                      let json = ((try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String : Any]) as [String : Any]??) else {
                    completion(nil, error)
                    return
                }
                completion(json, nil)
            })
            task.resume()
        }
    }
}
```

}

This is my Cloud Functions function that I created to try and get the ephemeral key:

```
exports.createEphemeralKeys = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, 
res) => {
var api_version = req.body.api_version;
var customerId = req.body.customer_id;

if (!api_version) {
 res.status(400).end();
 return;
}

let key = await stripe.ephemeralKeys.create(
  { customer: customerId },
  { stripe_version: api_version }
 );
 res.json(key);

});
```

This is looking like it's causing the problem, I know it's not the URL because I made another API call this morning with a paymentIntent Cloud Function and it had a 200 Status Code. I copied the code from the [Stripe docs](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios/basic#prepare-your-api) and had faith that it would work but it let me down. Any suggestions.

**UPDATE** I also checked the Cloud Functions server logs, and the function is executing with a 400 Error Status Code, so it's definitely the Cloud Function that is the issue, isn't the json in the `exports.createEphemeralKeys` function unmodified already, what else do I need to add for it to work?

Comment: Do you have an error message in console when this happens? Also is `TicketFormViewController` supposed to be a ViewController with its own `TicketFormViewController.xib`? Or are you using a Storyboard for it?

Comment: I just get a warning, saying `warning: could not execute support code to read Objective-C class data in the process. This may reduce the quality of type information available.`. No the `TicketFormViewController` does not have a `.xib` file, I'm using storyboards. @Larme

Comment: So `super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)` doesn't make sens since you are configured it in a Storyboard. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24035984/instantiate-and-present-a-viewcontroller-in-swift But `MyAPIClient` shouldn't know about `TicketFormViewController` Don't put `getUsersStripeCustomerID` inside it.

Comment: That's how they had it in the [docs](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios/basic#prepare-your-api). I need the `getUsersStripeCustomerID`, the user could be different every time, so that's a must have, plus I removed it to see and it was still giving the same error regardless. @Larme

Comment: Im going to edit the question I moved the block of code into a CheckoutViewController and it's giving a different error now. @Larme

Comment: Code in Step 2 is independ of ViewController, and it should be independ from it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230102/discussion-between-dsonawave-and-larme).

Comment: What is the assertion failure message?

Comment: Cannot parse the ephmeral key. Make sure backend is sending unmodified JSON @Paulw11

Answer (score 0):

After days of just trying to figure it out, I finally got help from a member in the Slack chat.

I got rid of the `if` statement, changed `stripe_version` to `apiVersion` because it was deprecated.

```
exports.createEphemeralKeys = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
var api_version = req.query.api_version;
var customerId = req.query.customer_id;

const key = await stripe.ephemeralKeys.create(
  { customer: customerId },
  { apiVersion: api_version}
);
res.json(key);

});
```

I also changed `req.body` to `req.query`. The JSON now prints in the console, but there's still a lot left I need to figure out.