# How can i present programmatically made ViewController on button click

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, navigation

I have this custom UIViewController. It is not connected to anything storyBoard and want to present on clicking a button

```
class SeeListsViewController: UIViewController {
   
    var tableView = UITableView()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.setUpTableView()
        view.addSubview(tableView)
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
}
```

How can i do that. I know the storyBoard way but this one has no identifier and it is all programmatically made

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Instantiate and Present a viewController in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24035984/instantiate-and-present-a-viewcontroller-in-swift)

Comment: Samo, samo, run a search, run a search...

Answer (score 0):

The solution below if you have SeeListsViewController in the storyboard and make sure the storyboard identifier is also SeeListsViewController:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "<Your storyboard name>", bundle: nil)
let listVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: SeeListsViewController.self)
self.present(listVC, animated: true)
```

A programmatic way to present if you don't have a view controller in the storyboard and all the UI components should be designed programmatically in your viewcontroller

```
let navVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: SeeListsViewController())
    navVC.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    self.present(navVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```