# view controller storyboard not displaying

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I am a beginner on Xcode and I am trying to embed YouTube video to child controllers of a side menu, but I can't connect my view controller file and my UI view controllers on the storyboard.
I am coding a side menu controller and the child views controllers are called using:

```
class Course2ViewController: UIViewController, MenuControllerDelegate2 {
    private var sideMenu: SideMenuNavigationController?
    
    private let abaController = abaViewController()
    private let abbController = abbViewController()
    private let abcController = abcViewController()
    private let abdController = abdViewController()
    

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let menu = MenuController2(with: SideMenuItem2.allCases)
        
        menu.delegate = self
        
        sideMenu = SideMenuNavigationController(rootViewController: menu)
        sideMenu?.leftSide = true
        
        SideMenuManager.default.leftMenuNavigationController = sideMenu
        SideMenuManager.default.addPanGestureToPresent(toView: view)

        AddChildControllers()
    }
    
    private func AddChildControllers() {
        addChild(abaController)
        addChild(abbController)
        addChild(abcController)
        addChild(abdController)
        
        view.addSubview(abaController.view)
        view.addSubview(abbController.view)
        view.addSubview(abcController.view)
        view.addSubview(abdController.view)
        
        abaController.view.frame = view.bounds
        abbController.view.frame = view.bounds
        abcController.view.frame = view.bounds
        abdController.view.frame = view.bounds
        
        abaController.didMove(toParent: self)
        abbController.didMove(toParent: self)
        abcController.didMove(toParent: self)
        abdController.didMove(toParent: self)
        
        abaController.view.isHidden = true
        abbController.view.isHidden = true
        abcController.view.isHidden = true
        abdController.view.isHidden = true
    }
    
    @IBAction func didTapMenuButton2() {
        present(sideMenu!, animated: true)
    }
    
    func didSelectMenuItem2(named: SideMenuItem2) {
        sideMenu?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        
            title = named.rawValue
            switch named {
        case.aba:
                abaController.view.isHidden = false
                abbController.view.isHidden = true
                abcController.view.isHidden = true
                abdController.view.isHidden = true
            
        case.abb:
                abaController.view.isHidden = true
                abbController.view.isHidden = false
                abcController.view.isHidden = true
                abdController.view.isHidden = true
            
        case.abc:
                abaController.view.isHidden = true
                abbController.view.isHidden = true
                abcController.view.isHidden = false
                abdController.view.isHidden = true
        
        case.abd:
                abaController.view.isHidden = true
                abbController.view.isHidden = true
                abcController.view.isHidden = true
                abdController.view.isHidden = false
            }
    }

}
```

then, I tried to connect my abaViewController file to a new view controller on storyboard by giving the later the class "abaViewController", but my view controller on storyboard is not displayed. Any tips/solutions?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24036067/8192960 is this helpful ?

Answer (score 0):

**Here's a look at how to create a Story Board directly from Swift UI**

If you're finding SwiftUI a little too complicated to begin with (most people do) I really **recommend choosing 'Storyboard' or 'UIKit' on your next project**. It allows you to **easily add view controllers and quickly allow buttons to move to other view controllers** by just holding the button, then 'Control', then the new screen. UIKit also allows you to **manage every aspect of your design visuall**y (also managing formatting and constraints) **without a single line of code**. What's even better is that you can **combine both SwiftUI and UIKit together**.

```
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MyStoryboardName", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("someViewController") as! UIViewController
// Alternative way to present the new view controller
self.navigationController?.showViewController(vc, sender: nil)
```